# jQuery validate plugin: accept only German letters

Tags: regex, string, jquery-validate

I am looking for a method for the jquery validate plugin (http://bassistance.de/jquery-plugins/jquery-plugin-validation/), that only accepts letters, including the German so called Umlaute (öäüÖÄÜß).. I googled a bit, but unfortunately couldn't find anything. I'm not good with regex, so I failed writing my own rule..
Do you have any idea? Any help is appreciated! Thx in advance! :)

Here is my method so far:

```
jQuery.validator.addMethod("lettersonly", function(value, element) {
      return this.optional(element) || /^[a-zA-ZüöäÜÖÄß]+$/i.test(value);
    }, "Letters only please");
```

**SOLUTION**: The method works! The problem was that the meta tag "content-type" was set wrong to ISO, but it has to be UTF-8 of course. `<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />`

Comment: Tag `german` removed as part of the [**2012 cleanup**](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/128315/the-great-stack-overflow-tag-question-cleanup-of-2012).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
[a-zA-Z\u0196\u0228\u0214\u0246\u0220\u0252\u0223]
```

These are the unicode characters for german letters, including the normal letters.

And this is normal :

```
[a-zA-ZüöäÜÖÄß]
```

It depends on what your input is.

The above matches single letters. Since you provide no sample input we can't make the regex rule more specific!

Comment: Thank you for your quick answer! Unfortunately I couldn't get it to work with both expressions, it still shows an error if I enter an "umlaut". I inserted my method in my question. Maybe you can find the mistake. Thx! :)

Comment: I found the problem. The backend programmer changed the meta content-type to iso.. I changed it back to utf-8. Now it works!! Thank you!