# jQuery Validate Plugin: German Umlauts not working

Tags: jquery, html, regex, jquery-validate

I am using the jQuery Validation Plugin () and I also found already an answer here on StackOverflow ([jQuery validate plugin: accept only German letters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7808390/jquery-validate-plugin-accept-only-german-letters)) but the provided solution is still not working for me.

I have umlauts (special characters) like Ö,Ü,ä,ß in my language and I use the following code, so that no numbers are allowed in my input field. Unfortunately as soon as someone enters an umlaut, I get the message that no numbers are allowed. Can someone tell me what I did wrong:

jQuery Code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function(){
    $.validator.addMethod('city', function(value, element, param) {
    var nameRegex = /^[a-zA-ZäüöÄÜÖß]+$/;
    return value.match(nameRegex);
  }, 'No numbers are allowed.');
});
</script>
```

I also tried the following approach:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $.validator.addMethod('city', function(value, element, param) {
        var nameRegex = /^[a-zA-Z\u0196\u0228\u0214\u0246\u0220\u0252\u0223]+$/;
        return value.match(nameRegex);
    }, 'No numbers are allowed.');
});
</script>
```

My HTML input field:

```
<div class='row'>
    <div class='col-md-12'>
        <label>City::<span class='color-red'>*</span></label>
        <input type='text' name='city' id='city' class='form-control' required>
    </div>
</div>
```

My website has charset=utf-8! Any idea what I am doing wrong? Everything else with jquery validation plugin works like a charm except this problem. Any help would be appreciated. If someone needs more details please let me know.

Answer (score 0):

I think you might misunderstand the naming of rules versus the naming of fields.  Your method (rule) is named `city`... however, just because your field is also named `city`, does not mean this rule is automatically applied to this field.  You'll still have to declare it on any fields.

I recommend you adjust the naming and follow one of these options...

---

**1.  Inline by class**

create the rule:

```
$.validator.addMethod('your_rule', function(value, element) {...
```

assign the rule by `class`:

```
<input type='text' name='city' class='form-control your_rule' ....
```

There is no `param` argument in the `.addMethod()` function because your function does not accept parameters.  If you accepted parameters, then you could not assign the rule by `class`.

---

**2. Within the `rules` object**

create the rule:

```
$.validator.addMethod('your_rule', function(value, element) {....
```

assign the rule by `.validate()` method:

```
$('#yourForm').validate() {
    rules: {
        city: {      // <- FIELD NAME
            your_rule: true   // <- RULE NAME
        },
        ....
    },....
```

If you need to pass parameters into the custom method/rule/function, then you would use #2.

```
$.validator.addMethod('your_rule', function(value, element, param) {....

$('#yourForm').validate() {
    rules: {
        city: {      // <- FIELD NAME
            your_rule: param   // <- RULE NAME
        },
        ....
    },....
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
$.validator.addMethod("city", function(value, element) {
  return this.optional(element) || /^[a-zA-ZÄäÖöÜüß\- ]+$/i.test(value);
}, "No numbers are allowed" );
```

Comment: Please add some explanation for your code rather than posting code only. Additional explanation will be more helpful.